# Using jQuery's unwrap() to remove a class

Tags: jquery, unwrap

I want to remove the class of `emphasis` from all tags that have that class in a specific cell of the table.  I'm selecting the table cell content like this:

```
var answer = $('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').html();
```

In another place in the code, I'm using `unwrap()` like this:

```
$(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();
```

However, I'm not sure how to combine the two.  I tried this, but it failed:

```
var answer = $('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').html().(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();
```

Any ideas?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION #1:  I want to keep the HTML inside the tag.  So, if I have: `14 + 6 = <span class="emphasis">20</span>` I want to end up with `14 + 6 = 20`.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION #2:  The HTML in question is getting set as the value for a hidden `<input>` field like this `$('#answer').val(answer);`.  Gleb Kemarsky's solution is good, but it doesn't get applied the value for the input field for some reason.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION #3...

I have a `<table>` with some rows and cells.  In the first cell of the last row I have some content (`14 + 6 = <span class="emphasis">20</span>` for example).

I use `var answer = $('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').html();` to get the HTML of that cell, then I use `$('#answer').val(answer);` to update the value of a hidden `<input id="answer">`.

When that happens, I'd like to turn `14 + 6 = <span class="emphasis">20</span>` into `14 + 6 = 20` for the value of the hidden `<input id="answer">`, but leave it as `14 + 6 = <span class="emphasis">20</span>` in the table.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION #4...

The key is that any `<span>`s with the class of `emphasis` be removed.

This..
`<span class="emphasis"><div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">21</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span style="border-top-color: green;" class="denom_display">23</span></div></span>`

should end up as... 
`<div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">21</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span style="border-top-color: green;" class="denom_display">23</span></div>`

Comment: can OP contain HTML mark up as well

Comment: Use `.find()` not `.html()`

Comment: How about this.
`$('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').find(".emphasis").removeClass("emphasis");`

Comment: if you want to remove a class, why are you removing an element and not just  removing the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to remove the `<span>` tag from the answer

### 5) Create a copy of the HTML-element and apply the `.unwrap()` method

The same issue has been [solved by Redu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002839/6263942).

---

### 4) Delete `<span class="emphasis"></span>` from the answer (without nested tags)

```js
var answer = $( 'tr.problem_display_work:last td:first' ).html();
$( '#answer' ).val( answer.replace( /<span class="emphasis">(.*?)<\/span>/g, '$1' ) );
```

```css
.accent,
.emphasis {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
.accent   { background: yellow;  }
.emphasis { background: orange; }
table {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td><span class="accent">1</span> + <span class="accent">1</span> = <span class="emphasis">2</span></td>
    <td><span class="accent">2</span> + <span class="accent">2</span> = <span class="emphasis">4</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td><span class="accent">3</span> + <span class="accent">3</span> = <span class="emphasis">6</span></td>
    <td><span class="accent">4</span> + <span class="accent">4</span> = <span class="emphasis">8</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="answer" size="70">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### 3) Delete all html-tags from the answer by [the `.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var answer = $( 'tr.problem_display_work:last td:first' ).html();
$( '#answer' ).val( answer.replace( /<[^>]+>/g, '' ) );
```

```css
.emphasis {
  background: orange;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
table {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td>1 + 1 = <span class="emphasis">2</span></td>
    <td>2 + 2 = <span class="emphasis">4</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td>3 + 3 = <span class="emphasis">6</span></td>
    <td>4 + 4 = <span class="emphasis">8</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="answer">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### 2) Add the `.emphasis` class to your selector

```js
$( 'tr.problem_display_work:last td:first .emphasis' ).contents().unwrap();
```

```css
.emphasis {
  background: orange;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td>1 + 1 = <span class="emphasis">2</span></td>
    <td>2 + 2 = <span class="emphasis">4</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="problem_display_work">
    <td>3 + 3 = <span class="emphasis">6</span></td>
    <td>4 + 4 = <span class="emphasis">8</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### 1) Use [the `.find()` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
selectorAnswer = $( 'tr.problem_display_work:last td:first' );
selectorAnswer.find( '.emphasis' ).contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: @gtilflm I've added [mcve] into my answer. Please check the result.

Comment: I don't see that the class `emphasis` is being removed though.

Comment: @gtilflm How do you check this? https://i.gyazo.com/975d456488c11eba9afd5448e0e29e1a.gif

Comment: Wait... nevermind.  I was reading it incorrectly.  You're right.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this though.  I'll update my original post further.

Comment: It seems like `$('#answer').val(answer).find('.emphasis').contents().unwrap();` should work, but there is still `<span class="emphasis">20</span>` in the value of the input field with the id of `answer`.  I'll have to work on this more in the morning, but I'm signing off for now.

Comment: I've added another clarification to my original post.  Hopefully that will help.  It seems that the the solutions you've provided aren't working because I'm wanting to change the value of an `<input>` field.  Thoughts?

Comment: @gtilflm You can use the `.replace()` method to delete html-tags from the string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your answer 3.) Delete html-tags from the answer by the .replace() method is removing all `<span>`s.  Can that be adapted to just remove the ones that are of `class="emphasis"` (but leave the content of that `<span>` of course)?

Comment: @gtilflm You can check the code snippet above the header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115439/discussion-between-gtilflm-and-gleb-kemarsky).

Comment: For those interested, the completion of this answer can be found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002382/removing-a-class-from-value-in-an-input-tag)  Thanks to Gleb for his work!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.I understand that u want to remove 'emphasis' class from all cells of a table . The solution is..

$('tr.problem_display_work:last td:first').removeClass("emphasis");

Comment: I just clarified my question and what I want to end up with.