# Removing a class from value in an <input> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<input>` tag with some HTML as the value.  I want to remove any `<span>`s that have the class of "emphasis", but still retain the content in the `<span>`.  I also don't want any other `<span>`s removed.

Example Below:

This:

```
<input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" value="<span class="emphasis"><div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">21</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span style="border-top-color: green;" class="denom_display">23</span></div></span>"
```

should end up as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" value="<div class="fraction_display"><span class="numer_display">21</span><span class="bar_display">/</span><span style="border-top-color: green;" class="denom_display">23</span></div>"`
```

I've tried using jQuery with this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/4/)...

```js
function remove_emphasis_class (){
  var content = $('#answer').val(answer);
  var content_after = content.filter('span.emphasis').contents().unwrap();
  $('#answer').val(content_after);
  alert(content_after);
}
```

```css
.emphasis {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" value="2 + 5 = <span class='emphasis'>7</span>" name="answer" id="answer">
<br><br>
<button onclick="remove_emphasis_class();">Remove Class</button>
```

...but it's not working.  `content_after` ends up coming back as "[object Object]"  Any ideas?

Comment: best would be to convert it to html, query it, remove it, and set the inputs value back.  They way it is written, your html would not render..

Comment: That's invalid HTML, the opening quote for `class` closes the value of `value` attribute, and the rest of the content will be parsed as a mess ...

Comment: @epascarello: Can you give some guidance on how to convert it to HTML and query it?

Comment: You first need to work out this: `<input type="hidden" value="2 + 5 = <span class='emphasis'>7</span>" name="answer" id="answer">` -- you're putting HTML into the `value` attribute of your `<input>`?

Comment: what is this supposed to do? https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/3/

Comment: Yes, I'm submitting HTML as part of a form.  jsfiddle would not let me put double quotes on the `class="emphasis"` part, so I used single quotes.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: I don't know.  I didn't post that link.

Comment: @gtilflm it is your code!

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith:  I posted this: https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/, but not https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/3/.  I've tweaked things a bit here though: https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea

```js
//using string instead of reading value of the input aka var str = $(".foo").val();
var str = "2 + 5 = <span class='emphasis'>7</span>";
//convert the string to html
var temp = $("<div>").html(str);
//find the span and unwrap it
temp.find(".emphasis").contents().unwrap();
//get the html string without the span
var updated = temp.html();
//display it
console.log(updated);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

other option is to just read .text() instead of .html() and it will strip all html.

Answer (score 1):

One approach in which multiple span elements with `emphasis` class might exist in the input value, can be like this;

```js
var tempDir = document.createElement("div"),
        inp = document.getElementById("answer"),
    els2del,
    content = "";
tempDir.innerHTML = inp.value;
els2del = tempDir.querySelectorAll("span[class = 'emphasis']");
for (var i = 0; i < els2del.length; i++){
  content += els2del[i].innerHTML;
}
inp.value = content;
console.log(inp.value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" value="<span class='emphasis'><div class='fraction_display'><span class='numer_display'>21</span><span class='bar_display'>/</span><span style='border-top-color: green;' class='denom_display'>23</span></div></span>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
function remove_emphasis_class (){
        var answer = document.querySelector('#answer').value;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = answer;
        var selector = div.querySelector('.emphasis');
    var newContent = selector.innerHTML;
    div.querySelector('.emphasis').outerHTML = newContent;
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: This is really close!  Ideally, I'd like to not have the empty `<span></span>` part.  I've updated my fiddle with your function (https://jsfiddle.net/0xgx04pq/5/)  How would we remove the empty span?